# SQL Trigger affect just the first record

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a trigger called `movimentacoes`, this trigger should increase `integralizadas` column in `cooperados` table when a new record is added to the `mov` table. Actually it does, but just to the first record in `cooperados` table

here is my trigger

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER movimentacoes AFTER INSERT ON mov
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE cooperados c
        SET integralizadas = c.integralizadas + new.valor
    WHERE c.id = new.id_coop;


END;

$$

DELIMITER ;
```

cooperados table

```
id            | bigint(20) PRI  NULL    auto_increment
created_at    | timestamp       NULL    
updated_at    | timestamp       NULL    
nameCoop      | varchar(255)    NULL    
numCoop       | int(11)         NULL    
cpfCoop       | varchar(11)     NULL    
dtCad         | date            NULL    
dtDem         | date            NULL    
description   | text            NULL    
subscritas    | decimal(6,2)    NULL    
integralizadas| decimal(6,2)    NULL    
aintegralizar | decimal(6,2)    NULL    
status        | enum('ativo','inativo')
```

mov table

```
idMov       bigint(20) PRI  NULL    auto_increment
created_at  timestamp       NULL    
updated_at  timestamp       NULL    
id_coop     bigint(20)      NULL    
valor       decimal(6,2)    NULL
```

the trigger just works when the `cooperado.id` is 1

Comment: Could you add some information about the two tables?

Comment: What do you mean by `just to the first record`? The trigger will update all records that the `where` clause matches.

Comment: What happens if you try to update a different id on the cooperados table than 1? Does cooperados table have records at all for other ids? If not, then update cannot work, you need to insert the record first.

Comment: I can manually update table `cooperados` with no problem, no matter the id, but the trigger is only activated when I set a new record in id 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i found the answer, since my `integralizadas` column was null, my trigger couldn't affect it , now my `cooperados` table is like that:

```
id            | bigint(20) PRI  NULL    auto_increment
created_at    | timestamp       NULL    
updated_at    | timestamp       NULL    
nameCoop      | varchar(255)    NULL    
numCoop       | int(11)         NULL    
cpfCoop       | varchar(11)     NULL    
dtCad         | date            NULL    
dtDem         | date            NULL    
description   | text            NULL    
subscritas    | decimal(6,2)    NULL    
integralizadas| decimal(6,2)    NOT NULL <--    
aintegralizar | decimal(6,2)    NULL    
status        | enum('ativo','inativo')
```

ty everyone